# Maintain selected cells after sorting a table view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, selection

I have a table view with multiple selection enabled. Users are supposed to be able to select multiple options in a list and then change the sort order of the list. I would like to be able to keep the same cells selected, but the order of them will have changed from the sort. I'm not seeing a way to achieve this so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use custom cells that have a property `selected`, and toggle that property in the way you want? That way you'll know which cells were selected after sorting the table view using the `selected` property.

Comment: Will i have the same reference to the cells after calling tableView.reloadData()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "selected" indicator in your data structure, you could use it to rebuild the tableView selection.

If you can't add such an indicator to the data, you could perform your sort in two steps:  1) compute the new element indexes, 2) apply these indexes to your data array to perform the sort.

With the sort indexes, you can rebuild the selection based on the new location of the original indexes:

For example:

```
// Assuming your tableview is named "tableView",
// and the data array is named "dataArray",
// and you sort uses a member of dataArray called "sortKey"


// prepare list of new indexes for sorted data
let newIndexes   = dataArray.enumerated().sorted{ $0.1.sortKey < $1.1.sortKey }.map{$0.0}

// determine new indexes of current selection
let newSelection = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?
                   .map{IndexPath(row:newIndexes.index(of:$0.row)!, section:0)}

// sort and reload the data                            
dataArray        = newIndexes.map{ self.dataArray[$0] }
tableView.reloadData()

// reapply the selection
tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach{tableView.deselectRow(at:$0, animated:false)}
for indexPath in newSelection ?? []
{ self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none) }
```